# What does "it" refer to in "make it into the knockout stage"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, pronouns, dummy-pronouns

There is a sentence in a newspaper

> Revisit the Rugby World Cup - the first hosted in Asia and the first to see Japan make **it** into the knockout stage -with some of the best images of all the highs and lows.

1. I could not understand the **it** in the sentence. What does the it shows?
2. Is "the first" a subject in this sentence? Would someone help me understand the sentence grammatically please? I thought if "the first" is a subject, I assume "make" in it would have to become "makes"?
3. What does "Highs and lows" mean? I looked up the meaning in a dictionary shows the highs and lows in stocks. It doesn't match this sentence.

Sorry if it is not easy to understand. Please teach me how to break down the sentence grammatically.

Comment: Welcome! I realize this question is old, but if you see this: These are three great questions, but they should be asked separately. Please edit to focus on one question here, then post the other two (after checking to make sure no other question answers them well).

Answer (score 3):

"Make it into X" is an idiom meaning "achieve the goal of X."

Thus, the sentence means

> the first [cup] to see Japan achieve placement in the knockout stage ...

As is usual with sports-reporting, the style is colloquial and therefore difficult to parse according to strict rules of English grammar. The "it" here is formally an object, not a subject, but the lexical meaning of "make" in "make it to" and "make it into" **may** differ from the common meaning, and in those cases the "it" is there only because "make" is formally a transitive verb.

Comment: It is a little bit odd for a second language learner about the part "it" but I understood the part "it" and the meaning of l the sentence. Althogh I do not know I can consciously write "make it into" when I write the same sentence on my own due to what is because "make" is formally a trasitive verb. I just memorize the idiom first. I really really really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

"to make it" has a number of meanings. Here are the two most usual.

> > If you make it somewhere, you succeed in getting there, especially in
> > time to do something. So you did make it to America, after all. ...the
> > hostages who never made it home. I just made it!
>
> > If you make it, you are successful in achieving something difficult,
> > or in surviving through a very difficult period. I believe I have the
> > talent to make it. You're brave and courageous. You can make it.
> > https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-make-it

Comment: Likewise, "fake it" means to pretend, and leads to the phrase "Fake it until you make it", meaning to pretend that you are successful until, in part due to the pretense, you actually become successful.